# Sonos: Create playbackSession that automatically ends after finishing the playlist. No repeat

Tags: sonos

When I create a playbackSession and load a track/playlist with `loadStreamUrl`, this playlist repeats playing from the start after the last song was reached. I instead want it to stop at the end.

I tried to find a property similar to `playOnComplete` (payload of `loadStreamUrl`)  which starts playback automatically after buffering the track, just for ending playback after the track was played.

I also tried to use `playback->setPlayModes` to forbid repeating, but this is just ignored.

```
{
    "playModes": {
       "repeat": false
    }
  }
```

I know this is possible by setting up an Event Callback and process the playbackStatus events, but I am looking for a simple "fire-and-forget" solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `loadStreamUrl` command is for streaming radio. Since you're playing a playlist, you should use `loadCloudQueue`.

Use `loadCloudQueue` with a `mediaUrl` for the [`track`](https://developer.sonos.com/reference/types/playback-objects/#track) instead of a SMAPI `MusicObjectId` if you don't want to set up a SMAPI server. See [`loadCloudQueue`](https://developer.sonos.com/reference/control-api/playbacksession/load-cloud-queue/) and [Play audio (cloud queue)](https://developer.sonos.com/build/content-service-get-started/play-audio/) for details.

Alternatively, you can try the undocumented `loadQueue` command. `loadQueue` works like `loadCloudQueue` but it doesn't require a cloud queue. To play a track without a cloud queue, send the following calls:

1. [`createSession`](https://developer.sonos.com/reference/control-api/playbacksession/create-session/)
2. `loadQueue` (described below)
3. [`skipToItem`](https://developer.sonos.com/reference/control-api/playbacksession/skip-to-item/)

### loadQueue

Initializes the Sonos queue with custom metadata and playback policies. Use this command with [`skipToItem`](https://developer.sonos.com/reference/control-api/playbacksession/skip-to-item/) to send a track to the player. The player stops playing at the end of the track.

### Parameters

*Name | Type | Description*

`metadata` | [`container`](https://developer.sonos.com/reference/types/playback-objects/#container) | Container metadata describing the queue. This could be a programmed radio station, an album, a playlist, etc.

`policies` | [`playbackPolicy`](https://developer.sonos.com/reference/types/playback-objects/#policies) | Playback policies for the session.

### Sample requests

```
POST [base URL]/groups/{groupId}/playbackSession
{...}

POST [base URL]/playbackSessions/{sessionId}/playbackSession/queue
{...}

POST [base URL]/playbackSessions/{sessionId}/playbackSession/skipToItem
{...}
```

See [Control API list](https://developer.sonos.com/reference/control-api-list/) for the base URL.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for replying! Actually I want to play just a single track (MP3 file on AWS S3). Doing this via `loadCloudQueue`, as I understand, would require me to deploy a whole Cloud Queue Server + SMAPI Server setup. This seems oversized for playing just a single mp3. Can I use `loadCloudQuere` in a simpler manner? Or do you see another possibility to archive my goal?
I also looked into the `audioClip` feature, but this would of course exclude older Sonos devices which do not support it.

Comment: Thanks for the support! This is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Tried to use the loadQueue command but there is just an empty `{}` result returned.
Is this feature already canceled?